# GWT uiBinder TabPanel - Tab title from dictionary

Tags: java, gwt, dictionary, uibinder, tabpanel

I want to change GWT TabPanel behaviour, so it would allow me to set tab titles not directly in .ui.xml files, but in some kind of dictionary class.

Standard tabPanel looks like this:

```
<gwt:TabPanel ui:field="tabPanel">
  <gwt:Tab text="Some tab title">
    <gwt:VerticalPanel>
      <!-- components -->
    </gwt:VerticalPanel>
  </gwt:Tab>
  <gwt:Tab text="Other tab title">
    <gwt:VerticalPanel>
      <!-- components -->
    </gwt:VerticalPanel>
  </gwt:Tab>
</gwt:TabPanel>
```

I want to use external dictionary with all labels/titles, so I could get the label/title by it's dictionary key, e.g:

```
Tab.Title.some=Some tab title
Tab.Title.other=Other tab title
```

So my .ui.xml file should looks like this:

```
<gwt:TabPanel ui:field="tabPanel">
  <gwt:Tab text="Tab.Title.some">
    <gwt:VerticalPanel>
      <!-- components -->
    </gwt:VerticalPanel>
  </gwt:Tab>
  <gwt:Tab text="Tab.Title.other">
    <gwt:VerticalPanel>
      <!-- components -->
    </gwt:VerticalPanel>
  </gwt:Tab>
</gwt:TabPanel>
```

In all other cases (labels, table headers etc) I was able to extend component class and overload setText(String text) method. But for Tab there is only an interface and I'm not sure what to do with it to get desirable effect. Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the i18n support for gwt this is probably exactly what you are looking for.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinderI18n.html

Comment: The question is not what to use, but how to extend gwt TabPanel to make such things possible. But thanks anyway